# formulating an SSRS query to include zero/empty rows in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on a SSRS report and I'm having an issue with my Plant name not showing when there is no data available for the date range selected.

The far left column, first row (technically the 2nd by the image) is where my plant name should appear at all times:

[image]

[image]

Essentially the first image showed just my blank rows/columns. The first column, first row is where my plant name should be at all times. The remaining columns are my returned data based on date selection.

The second image would show everything working as it should when there is data.

I'm grouping by PlantCode in SSRS which is what gives my my plant name. I don't know how to get the plant name to appear even if there is not data available.

Is this possible?

I THOUGHT I could use something like `iif(salesvolume is NOTHING, [PlantCODE],[PlantCode])`

Here is the database query for the report

```
SELECT
    PInv.[Plant_Numer],
    PInv.[Plant_Code],
    PInv.{Department_number],
    PInv.[Inventory_Volume],
    Pinv.[Inventory_Date], -- 'Last Inventory Date'
    pls.[Actual_Volume],
    pls.[Budget_Volume],
    ppf.[Good_Output_Product_Units] AS 'Production Volume', -- 'Next Day Production
    CASE 
        WHEN coalesce (pls.[Acutal_Volume],0) = 0 and coalesce (pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars],0) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ((pls.[Actual_Sales_Dollars/pls.[Actual_Volume])) AS 'Average Price' -- 'Next Day Sales'
FROM
    [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Production_Fact] pf
    inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Production_Process_Fact] ppf on ppf.production_number = pf.production_number
    inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Process] prc on prc.process_number = pf.process_number
    inner join [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Department] dpt on dpt.department_number = prc.department_number
    inner join [WoodProduction_New].[dbo].[Plywood_Layup_Sales] pls on pls.procesS_number = pf.procesS_number
    inner join [WoodProduction_New].[dbo].[Process_Inventory] Pinv on PInv.[Inventory_Date] = pf.date 
        and pls.product_date = pf.date 
        and dpt.department_number = pinv.department_number
WHERE
    pf.date between @BeginningDate and @EndingDate
```

Comment: and so now my other lack of knowledge is about to be shown... how do I do that? I just have the image saved to my desktop. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the database query you are using to generate your report data?  That is where I would recommend making your change to return the Plantcode every time.

Comment: I'll try. P.Campbell added my images and so when I edit it says that I can't because I've tried to add images. Bare with me!

Comment: Heres a link... http://imgur.com/ZBTBf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change your query so that Process Inventory is your primary table and all other tables are `LEFT JOINED` to that table. That way the Plant Number & Code will show up regardless of whether there is matching data in the other tables.

This syntax is probably not completely correct, but I would start out by changing your `FROM` clause to look something like this:

```
FROM
    [WoodProduction_New].[dbo].[Process_Inventory] Pinv
    LEFT JOIN [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Production_Fact] pf 
        ON PInv.[Inventory_Date] = pf.date
    LEFT JOIN [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Production_Process_Fact] ppf 
        ON ppf.production_number = pf.production_number
    LEFT JOIN [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Process] prc 
        ON prc.process_number = pf.process_number
    LEFT JOIN [TrueOpportunity].[dbo].[Department] dpt 
        ON dpt.department_number = prc.department_number 
        AND dpt.department_number = pinv.department_number
    LEFT JOIN [WoodProduction_New].[dbo].[Plywood_Layup_Sales] pls 
        ON pls.process_number = pf.process_number 
        AND pls.product_date = pf.date
```

Experiment with that and see if you can get it to display the data that you want.

Comment: it ALMOST works. I did manage to get it to display for one thing but all of my data was the same for all of the plants for the week. But, I will play around with it and see what I can come up with. Thanks!